# Iphone 7 plus craches on application start With Springboard Error iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, springboard, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

At application launch, my app is crashing with the following stack trace. The weird thing is, the app runs fine on any other iOS 10 device including the iPhone 7, but crashes on iPhone 7 Plus. The error looks to be in the new UserNotifications framework, but the app isn't using the framework at all.

```
Incident Identifier: 6AE7679F-762C-428F-8654-8A51FCD22877
CrashReporter Key:   87e5483b521d6b520f499d858bdd9f79f1f3d423
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,4
Process:             SpringBoard [910]
Path:                /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:          com.apple.springboard
Version:             50 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.springboard [71]


Date/Time:           2016-09-20 12:41:08.8599 -0500
Launch Time:         2016-09-20 12:32:47.6263 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.1 (14A403)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  38

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000182fd1198 GSEventRunModal + 180
6   UIKit                           0x0000000187527818 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
7   UIKit                           0x0000000187522550 UIApplicationMain + 208
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001805305b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018205cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018207d60c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x0000000187e9ce6c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018215a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018205cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001820b12a0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   UIKit                           0x0000000187b84000 -[UIStatusBarServerThread main] + 840
8   Foundation                      0x000000018215a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018205cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   CoreBrightness                  0x00000001919928fc -[BrightnessSystemClientInternal main] + 1392
7   Foundation                      0x000000018215a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  NetworkLoad
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   GeoServices                     0x00000001893401e0 _runNetworkThread + 428
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   SpringBoard                     0x000000010010c8cc 0x10005c000 + 723148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.springboard.icongeneration
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   SpringBoard                     0x000000010010c9cc 0x10005c000 + 723404
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019abcafe8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019abf0f14 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018159b8d4 CFRunLoopRun + 112
6   CoreMotion                      0x00000001883957dc 0x188334000 + 399324
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  SBWiFiManager callback thread
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018205cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001820b12a0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   SpringBoard                     0x00000001001810f8 0x10005c000 + 1200376
8   Foundation                      0x000000018215a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018205cb1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   CoreBrightness                  0x00000001919928fc -[BrightnessSystemClientInternal main] + 1392
7   Foundation                      0x000000018215a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  CommonUtilities-WiFi-Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018062416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180623fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181621cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018161f908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018159b8d4 CFRunLoopRun + 112
6   CommonUtilities                 0x0000000183904c20 0x1838fe000 + 27680
7   Foundation                      0x000000018215a50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707860 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180707770 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180705188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 28:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180705188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 30:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 31:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 32:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 33:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 34:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 35:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 36:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 37:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 38 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.usernotificationsserver.NotificationSchedulingService
Thread 38 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001805545cc strlen + 12
1   UserNotificationsServer         0x000000019c49eed4 UNNotificationAttachmentSandboxExtensionIssuingBlock_block_invoke + 96
2   UserNotifications               0x000000019aeb71c0 -[UNSecurityScopedURL encodeWithCoder:] + 104
3   Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
4   UserNotifications               0x000000019aebe4b0 -[UNNotificationAttachment encodeWithCoder:] + 208
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
6   Foundation                      0x00000001820bdeb0 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 264
7   Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
8   UserNotifications               0x000000019aec20ec -[UNNotificationContent encodeWithCoder:] + 104
9   Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
10  UserNotifications               0x000000019aeb8074 -[UNNotificationRequest encodeWithCoder:] + 104
11  Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
12  Foundation                      0x00000001820bdeb0 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 264
13  Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
14  Foundation                      0x0000000182055c5c encodeInvocationArguments + 308
15  Foundation                      0x00000001820558c4 -[NSXPCEncoder encodeInvocation:] + 268
16  Foundation                      0x0000000182055780 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 684
17  Foundation                      0x0000000182266838 __51-[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeMessageWithData:]_block_invoke.133 + 720
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018167a0b8 __forwarding_prep_b___ + 88
19  UserNotificationsServer         0x000000019c4bcd64 __119-[UNSUserNotificationServerConnectionListener getPendingNotificationRequestsForBundleIdentifier:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 72
20  UserNotificationsServer         0x000000019c493ad4 __107-[UNSNotificationSchedulingService getPendingNotificationRecordsForBundleIdentifier:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke + 60
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001804fd200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001804fd1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018050b444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805009a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018050b940 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 360
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018050d38c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018050d0ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001807052c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 39:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 40:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180642a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018070536c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180704db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 38 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000101b72200   x3: 0x0000000000000012
    x4: 0x00000001703103c0   x5: 0x000000000000001f   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001a61d6000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000003fff  x11: 0x0000000101b74000
   x12: 0xffffffffffffc000  x13: 0x0000000101b74000  x14: 0x0000000000008012  x15: 0x0000000000002400
   x16: 0x00000001805545c0  x17: 0x00000001800c6e90  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000001a6479598  x21: 0x0000000171a5cd70  x22: 0x0000000187fe9454  x23: 0x0000000171a5cd70
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000048  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000040
   x28: 0x0000000000000038   fp: 0x000000016f2e2210   lr: 0x000000019c49eed4
    sp: 0x000000016f2e2210   pc: 0x00000001805545cc cpsr: 0x60000000
```